# Ubuntu Power ON getting fsck error most of the time

Tags: 20.04, mount, fsck

I Have installed Ubuntu 20.04 in one of the Core i7 based SBC . It works fine for several power OFF and ON. Sometimes when I power OFF and ON again, it is saying file system check error and asking to run fsck manually.

when I run `fsck -f /dev/nvme0np2` command it will asks for several yes prompts and finally it will say some error and not able to restart the system.

All the times my system is operating properly and doing proper shutdowns.

I am attaching few screen shots that I have taken when I got this issue.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This may indicate a failing hard drive.

Comment: Thanks for your reply . Do I need to replace the Hard drive with other or shall I reinstall OS again ?

Comment: If the drive is failing, you will need to replace the drive of course. You can of course first attempt a reinstall and see whether the problem returns or not.

Comment: Its second time we installed OS again . after the 2nd installation also we got issue but not immediately . It works fine for several restarts but suddenly got this issue .

Comment: OK, that confirms what I suggested.

Comment: OK thanks for the confirmation , I will replace the SBC itself .     What will be major SW side concern/considerations  to avoid fsck errors .